# ConTeXt's user namespace seems somewhat empty

Tags: context, luatex, lua

With

```
ConTeXt  ver: 2010.05.24 13:05 MKIV  fmt: 2010.12.18  int: english/english
```

the ConTeXt code

```
\starttext
   \message{one}
   \directlua{print(1)}
   \message{two}
   \usercode{print(2)}
\stoptext
```

gives (excerpted)

```
systems         : begin file minex.tex at line 1
one1
 two
! LuaTeX error <private user instance>:1: attempt to call global 'print' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        <private user instance>:1: in main chunk.
\usercode #1->\directlua 1{protect("userdata")#1}

l.5    \usercode{print(2)}
```

This I interpret as the `print` variable being bound in the usual way to the Lua basic function in the default namespace, but unbound in Context's `user` namespace; likewise all the other basic Lua functions that I checked are unbound in the user namespace.

Is this behaviour intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal globals are inside the table `global` within usercode:

```
\starttext
   \usercode{global.print(2)}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Yes, I've got my code to work, thank you.  This isn't want the [Programming in LuaTeX](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX) wiki page says: it says global contains "all the Lua functions defined by ConTeXt (but not the inbuilt Lua functions)"; additionally many tables (they're not "normal" globals?) are in the user namespace, such as stdin, tex - is this documented fully anywhere?

Comment: @Charles: I wrote the Programming in Lua page. IIRC, some of this was documented in the MkIV manual, some in the source code; rest I figured from trial and error. I will check if something changed recently or if I was wrong from the beginning and appropriately modify the page. The page needs an overhaul anyways (no mention of `\ctxcommands` and family, linking to the cld page, etc).

Comment: @Aditya: It was enough to get started, thank you!  The version of the Mk IV manual that I looked at (probably not up-to-date) seems rather impressionistic on this.